# JsfUnit without JBoss in spring web app - maven dependency setup

Tags: java, jsf, maven, dependencies, jsfunit

I can't find an easy JSFUnit setup for my pom anywhere. What repository do I use and which dependencies? We have a running web app with JSF and Spring. Can't be that hard to get JSFUnit into the mix..?!

Also we want to run the tests from Eclipse (I think I found something there) and via Maven when building the artifacts on jenkins.

Can anyone please post their dependency setup (as well as maven build cycle integration)?
Thanks!

Comment: I would also love to be able to use JSFUnit to test my Spring/JSF/JPA apps, but as of today [it doesn't seem to be supported](https://community.jboss.org/thread/18697).